# Dropdown from enum jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, enums, dropdown

Could you please assist me for the following code? I am trying to get ENUM values into dropdown but dropdown displayes nothing.

create.jsp

```
    <select name="labOwner" name="labOwner" id="labOwner">
      <option value="Select"></option>
        <c:forEach var="labOwner" items="${labOwner}">
            <li>${labOwner}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

LabController.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lab/labOwner")
public ModelAndView getPages(){
    List<LabOwner> labOwner = new ArrayList<LabOwner>( Arrays.asList(LabOwner.values() ));
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("create");
    model.addObject("labOwner", labOwner);

    return model;
}
```

LabOwner.java

```
public enum LabOwner {
    G_ONLY("G"),
    D_ONLY("D"),
    GS("S/D ");

    private String labOwner;

    LabOwner(String labOwner) {
        this.labOwner = labOwner;
    }

    public String getLabOwner() {
        return labOwner;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring `form` tag to bind your property:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<form:select path="labOwnerBeanPropertyNameHere" id="labOwner">
     <c:forEach var="labOwnerValue" items="${labOwner}">
         <form:option value="${labOwnerValue}">${labOwnerValue}</form:option>
     </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Note that you'll want to display the value of each item in your `labOwner` list, rather than the list as a whole.

Also, your controller code can be simplified to:

```
@GetMapping("/lab/labOwner")
public String getPages(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("labOwner", 
                       new ArrayList<LabOwner>(Arrays.asList(LabOwner.values());
    return "create";
}
```

Finally, take a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) and use the `@Getter` annotation for your `Enum` class.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can set labOwnerBeanProperty without xml

Comment: Your form will have a backing bean - typically a simple POJO that has the properties that you have on your form.  It's how you would capture your user's chosen values (you can persist them to a DB).  Have a look on SO and elsewhere - plenty of examples!